# Get the value of another field for validation in Yup Schema

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I am using Formik with Yup for validation and TypeScript

I have a field that needs to validate based on the value of another field.

The first field is called price and the second field is called tips. The max tip value is 10% of the what ever the price entered is.

I tried to create validation for this using the following:

```
   tips: yup.number()
    .min(0, `Minimum tip is $0`)
    .max( parseFloat(yup.ref('price'))* 0.1, "Maximum tip is 10% of the price.");
```

however this doesn't compile because yup.ref returns a Ref. How can I get the value of the price field in this validation?

Comment: Does `yup.reach('price')` help? From what I read [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/435), you can access object schemas using `reach`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`number.max` cannot reference other field and calculate with it at validation.

If you want to do this, you need to implement own schema with `mixed.test`.
Here is a example.

```
  tips: number()
    .min(0, `Minimum tip is $0`)
    .test({
      name: 'max',
      exclusive: false,
      params: { },
      message: '${path} must be less than 10% of the price',
      test: function (value) {
          // You can access the price field with `this.parent`.
          return value <= parseFloat(this.parent.price * 0.1)
      },
    }),
```

Here is [doc](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestoptions-object-schema).
You can check and try how it works [here](https://runkit.com/cashewnuts/yup-custom-max-example).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: what would be the equivalent in a function component? because this is undefined.

Comment: @loekTheDreamer

In case of functional approach you can pass a second argument with context like this:

test: function (value, ctx) {
  return value <= parseFloat(ctx.parent.price * 0.1)
},

Answer (score 16):

if you don't want to use **this.parent** to access the other properties values you can use the [context](https://github.com/jquense/yup).

```
tips: number()
.min(0, `Minimum tip is $0`)
.test(
  'max',
  '${path} must be less than 10% of the price',
  (value, context) => value <= parseFloat(context.parent.price * 0.1),
),

// OR

tips: number()
.min(0, `Minimum tip is $0`)
.test({
      name: 'max',
      exclusive: false,
      params: { },
      message: '${path} must be less than 10% of the price',
      test: (value, context) => value <= parseFloat(context.parent.price * 0.1),
    }),
```

Comment: Especially useful when using typescript - this is the way to go - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For referencing other field value we can use this.parent or ctx.parent in case if our value is not nested.

```
object({
   title: string(),
   price: string().test('test-name', 'test-message', (value, ctx) => {
       let title = ctx.parent.title;
   }),
   foo: string()
       .test('test-name1', 'test-message1', function (value) {
           let title = this.parent.title
       })
})
```

> but if we have nested value parent is going to give parent of nested
> value. in this case parent is not going to work if we want to access
> very parent value. we can access parent value with ctx.from. ctx.from contains parents from bottom to top. for example:

```
object({
    title: string(),
    ourObject: object({
        param1: string(),
        param2: string()
            .test('test-name', 'test-msg', (value, ctx) => {
                let title = ctx.from[ctx.from.length - 1].value.title
            })
    })
})
```

or we can easily access any data we want with providing context to schema when validating

```
object({
    price: string(),
    foo: string()
        .test('test-name', 'test-message', (value, ctx) => {
            let arr = ctx.context.arr;
        })
})
    .validate({ price: 5, foo: 'boo' }, { context: { arr: [1, 2] } })
    .then(() => ...)
    .catch((err) => ...)
```

[doc](https://github.com/jquense/yup/tree/0398c63694c0737b5861db8dce05b662668864ea#schemavalidatevalue-any-options-object-promiseinfertypeschema-validationerror)

Answer (score 0):

```
    LIKE SO 

   .test((val,obj)=>{

     console.log(val,obj.parent.otherField)

    })

   val=>current field value
   obj=>object of the whole schema


   EXAMPLE::::


   date: yup.
    string()
    .required()
    .test('type', 'Date should be future date', (val) => {

   console.log(val);

    }),
   time: yup
   .string()
   .required()
   .test('type', 'Time should be future time', (val,obj) => {

    console.log(val,'in time val',obj.parent.date,'date')

   }),
```