# Yup validation based on value of another field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I've three fields : referenceMonth(string), openingDate(string), closingDate(string) in Formik form.
I would add an error to `openingDate` when `openingDat` isn't the same month as `referenceMonth`.

```
export const VALIDATION_SCHEMA = Yup.object().shape({
    'referenceMonth' : Yup.number().required(YUP_DEFAULT_ERROR_VALUE),
    'openingDate' : Yup.string().when(['referenceMonth', 'openingDate'], {
        is: (referenceMonth: string, openingDate: string) => 
             referenceMonth !== `${new Date(openingDate).getMonth()}`,
        then: Yup.string().required('Select right month')
    }),
})
```

Terminal says: **Error: Cyclic dependency, node was: "openingDate".**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value of another field for validation in Yup Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058945/get-the-value-of-another-field-for-validation-in-yup-schema)

Answer (score 10):

Fields that depend on each other, to be validated, needs to be sorted so that they are constructed in in the desired order. Can you try it this way by adding the fields that need validation at the end in that specific order:

```js
export const VALIDATION_SCHEMA = Yup.object().shape({
    'referenceMonth' : Yup.number().required(YUP_DEFAULT_ERROR_VALUE),
    'openingDate' : Yup.string().when(['referenceMonth', 'openingDate'], {
        is: (referenceMonth, openingDate) => 
             referenceMonth !== `${new Date(openingDate).getMonth()}`,
        then: Yup.string().required('Select right month')
    }),
}, [['referenceMonth', 'openingDate']])
```

Answer (score 5):

Since your validation for `openingDate` is pretty stright forward as in the schema for `openingDate` won't change (as per my understanding), i would suggest you to make use of `test` rather than `when`. You could replace your `when` with `test` like so

```
.test("dateTest", "Select right month", function (value) {
   return this.parent.referenceMonth !== `${new Date(value).getMonth()}`;
 })
```

Comment: Nice solution with `this.parent.` !